# Post Method in using request

Tags: python, post, button, python-requests, click

I am trying to simulate a click button on a page using request and python
My code is the following.
As usual, it is very simple: on this web page, just click on the button "Valider" and the file is download
But I am doing something wrong 
Perhaps someone can help me?
Thanks for your help

```
import requests

url = "https://www.doyoubuzz.com/denis-colliot/cv/download"
response = requests.post(url)
```

Thais

Comment: the website has download security

Comment: http://doc.doyoubuzz.com/ try using thier api

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I know their api, but I just want to learn how to do this and how to use de post functionnality of request.
I perform it with selenium for example but not with requests that's why my SOS :)

Thais